# Why can't I export in formats other than Sketchup and blender?

Tags: export

I wanted to convert a few 3d files from old sketchup versions to other formats like DirectX and PMX/PMD. I tried following instructions from different sources and I keep hitting this barrier. I make sure the addons are checked and saved but whenever I try to export them, it fails and gives me these errors (See Pic). I tried shrinking the model, merging parts into one, checking the updates for the addons all to no avail.

Any insight would be helpful!

addons used
-Sketchup addon Worked for importing to blender 2016 file year[image]
-DirectX X format
-Meshio PMX/PMD

Comment: Your question leaves a lot of search/quesswork to potential helpers. E.g. which instructions you followed, or where the addons came from. Not everybody here uses the same workflow as you did. If you can modify your question to give step-by-step instructions (better: minimal blend files showing the problem) to reproduce your issue, the probability of getting a useful answer rises.

Comment: From the error message it looks like your Russian object names are breaking it. Try renaming the objects using only latin characters.